# deploying nextjs app to elastic beanstalk getting error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After eb deploy, my build is failing with this error:

```
2023-08-16 19:28:26,665 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-08-16 19:28:26,665 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_build failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_build failed
```

I have tried all the best solutions, even zip and upload but not working.

Comment: @youssouf have you any answer for it?

Comment: Hi Ahsaan! Sorry I have no idea :( Hope you will find a solution soon !